# backgroundworker only triggering once

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, web-services, backgroundworker

I'm reading a file to memory, and then trying to do a webservice call for each line. What I'm trying to do is something like:
1. Read in the file
2. Create new thread - > perform web service call for line 1
3. Create new thread - > perform web service call for line 2
4. Update "status" box with result from service call 1 or 2 which ever one gets back first

So in other words I'm trying to do multiple web service calls for each line in the file, and update the status box as they come back. I don't want to make one call, and then start the second call after the first call has returned.

EDIT: forgot to mention that while debugging, I noticed that only one call is made because the `readFileBackgroundWorker.IsBusy` is `true` when going through the foreach loop, but if I remove that then I get an error `This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.`

Read file in:

```
private void uxReadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uxFileStatusLabel.Text = String.Empty;
        this.uxReadFileButton.Enabled = false;
        this.uxCancelReadingFileButton.Enabled = true;
        var clientList = ReadFile(uxFileNameBox.Text);

        foreach (var client in clientList)
        {
            if (readFileBackgroundWorker.IsBusy != true)
            {
                readFileBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(client);
            }
        }
    }

 private void readFileBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        ProcessClient((ClientObject)e.Argument, worker, e);
    }

 private void ProcessClient(ClientObject client, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            client.FileClientDischarge(SystemCode, UserName, Password);
            int percent = (int)(Math.Ceiling(((double)(client.RecordNumber + 1) / 121) * 100));
            worker.ReportProgress(percent, client);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            worker.CancelAsync();
        }
        e.Result = client.RecordNumber;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. Pretty simply put a web service call is already async. So, on the background worker, read the file one line at a time, attach to the web services call back event with an inline delegate, and inside that delegate call the report progress method. If its more than 15 lines of code inside that background worker it's too many probably if that makes sense. You don't need a new thread for each line - the web service call is already async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your background worker only runs once is that it's busy when you call `RunWorkerAsync()` the second time. You should create a background worker for every iteration of the loop.

```
private void uxReadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    uxFileStatusLabel.Text = String.Empty;
    this.uxReadFileButton.Enabled = false;
    this.uxCancelReadingFileButton.Enabled = true;
    var clientList = ReadFile(uxFileNameBox.Text);
    BackGroundWorker bgw;

    foreach (var client in clientList)
    {
        bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += readFileBackgroundWorker_DoWork;
        //bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += 

        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(client);
    }
}

private void readFileBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    ProcessClient((ClientObject)e.Argument, worker, e);
}

private void ProcessClient(ClientObject client, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        client.FileClientDischarge(SystemCode, UserName, Password);
        int percent = (int)(Math.Ceiling(((double)(client.RecordNumber + 1) / 121) * 100));
        worker.ReportProgress(percent, client);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        worker.CancelAsync();
    }
    e.Result = client.RecordNumber;
}
```

Please checkout this SO question on [Cancelling a BackGroundWorker DoWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471470/c-background-worker)

Comment: This worked... thanks for being so detailed and pointing out the `BackgroundWorker Cancel`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using multi threading as the foreach loop finishes before your worker does the job.

Answer (score 0):

you can start multiple backgroundworkers to do your webservice calls in parallel by using something like

```
foreach (var client in clientList)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(i);
    }
```